# python pdb unt at end of loop

Tags: python, pdb

I have been using pdb's "unt" command to step over list comprehensions with a single command. This works well unless the list comprehension happens to be at the end of the loop. Then the "unt" command steps over the entire loop.

It seems to me that this is a flaw in the definition of the "unt" command. Is there a reason why it wasn't defined as continuing execution until the current line changes, rather than waiting for it to increase?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I've encountered so far is that a list comprehension spanning multiple lines can be stepped out of using "unt" as it works now. With my proposal, "unt" would remain in the list comprehension.